# provide a combinatorial proof that $C_{n+1} = C_0C_n + C_1C_{n-1} + …. + C_kC_{n-k} + …C_nC_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing

(a) Let $C_n$ denote the number of ways of writing a valid list of open and closed parentheses of length $2n$ (valid means that at any point along the list, the number of open parentheses must be greater than or equal the number of closed parentheses). In the case of $n = 3$, there are 5 valid configurations:

((())), (())(), ()()(), (()()), ()(())

With $C_0 = 1$, provide a combinatorial proof that

$C_{n+1} = C_0C_n + C_1C_{n-1} + …. + C_kC_{n-k} + …C_nC_0$

(b) Show that $C_n$ also determines the number of paths in the plane from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, that always stay above the main diagonal $(y = x)$ if each step in the path is of the form $(1, 0)$, or $(0, 1)$ (i.e., unit distance due east or due north).

I can't seem to figure out this problem.

Comment: Try looking up Catalan numbers. That recurrence is not particularly useful. There is a closed form which is more helpful and which you should be able to discover.

Comment: The recursion just arises from considering the first time that a path from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,n+1)$ visits the diagonal after the start.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**.  For a valid bracket word of length $2n+2$, the first symbol must be a left bracket.  This will at some stage be matched by a right bracket.  So the word looks like
$$(\cdots)\cdots$$
where each $\cdots$ is a valid bracket word.  These two words between them contain $2n$ symbols.  See if you can finish the argument from here.